# What applications could knot theory have for probability and statistics.

Tags: knot-theory

A lot of my time is spent in the world of probability. I am curious if any knot theorists wish there were ideas in knot theory probabilists played with more often. I have seen applications of probability and combinatorics to knots, but not the reverse direction -- knots to probability.

Comment: Check here:  https://www.amazon.com/Random-Knotting-Linking-Amast-Computing/dp/9810220057/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1WRW3J5W6IIF5&keywords=Random+knots+mathematics+topology&qid=1672284187&sprefix=random+knots+mathematics+topology%2Caps%2C147&sr=8-3&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.006c50ae-5d4c-4777-9bc0-4513d670b6bc

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are looking for, but there are many random models of knots which are studied using probabilistic methods.  [Here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Models-of-random-knots-Even-Zohar/08a17fe3afcdbd05ee248d135470dd3a791a4b87) is one survey paper.  Is this what you mean?  If not, can you be more specific?